# pattern matching for firefox extension

Tags: json, firefox, firefox-addon

I've been trying to figure how to make  a pattern that loads a script.

https://twitter.com/fasc1nate/status/1582217359754162176
this is an example of a url that a would like to match.

specifically any twitter url that has /status/ anywhere in it.

i have tried with

```
"matches": ["*://*.twitter.com/*"]"
"matches": ["*://*.twitter.com/*/status"]"
"matches": ["*://*.twitter.com/*/status/*"]"
"matches": ["*://*.twitter.com/*/status/*/"]"
```

but i cant seem to get it.

Comment: the URL that you are using as an example does not have `www.` which based on your pattern matches it would pick up, BUT you have a `.` in all of the URLs before `twitter`, try removing that period in all of the URLs and see if it works.

Comment: that didn't work, but with or without the dot https://twitter.com/home works.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with [how to test a URL match pattern against a URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226491/how-to-test-a-url-match-pattern-against-a-url-string)

you can get the last two to match based on the URL that you gave as an example with

```
"matches": ["*//twitter.com/*/status/*"], 
"matches": ["*//twitter.com/*/status/*/"],
```